# mechanize doesn't submit form

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, www-mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm trying to login to http://chess.com/login so that I can access some download links but I can't seem to get mechanize to submit my login credentials.My code looks like this:

```
import mechanize

def login(username, password):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    login = br.open('http://chess.com/login')
    br.select_form(nr = 0)
    br.form['c1'] = username
    br.form['loginpassword'] = password
    br.method = 'POST'

    resp = br.submit()

    login_check = resp.read()

    testfile = open('test.html','w+')
    testfile.write(login_check)
```

However when I check the testfile html, it returns the login page, only with the form data input.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems the submit button used some javascript which mechanize doesn't support.Decided to use Selenium instead.